# "in the order it was received" and referring to position as "order"

Tags: phrases, sentence

I'm sure many of you have been in this situation—I'll be on hold for a bit and some automated voice will say

> Your call will be answered in the order it was received.

I understand what they're saying, but I believe it's phrased wrong.  They're saying that my call has a place in a sequence of calls, and they'll *all* be answered in the same order in which they were received.

There must be, as far as I know, multiple (or, a list of) things in the subject of a sentence in order for the action on the subject to be done in an *order*.

I generally steer away from customer service phone calls, but in the few that I've done, I've heard this phrasing more than the alternatives, which can be something like:

> Calls are answered in the order in which they were received.

To me, this latter usage seems more reasonable, and "correct" (because I've always seen the "in which" construction as grammatical—though it seems awkward to many).

I'm wondering—

1. (based on a comment) Is it acceptable to refer to the *position* an of an item in a list as its "order"?
2. Is the former quoted phrase more common and accepted?  If not, is its implication well understood, or does it warrant rephrasing?

(edit based on my [meta question/answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5058/why-was-my-question-put-on-hold?noredirect=1) regarding this )

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seems to be complaining about a pet-peeve and not really about the English Language.

Comment: I'm not complaining as much as I'm asking if it's actually poor phrasing or if it bothers anyone else.

Comment: Do you think I should rephrase it?

Comment: Well, do you think the message itself should be rephrased? If so, how? The phrasing is not really the problem, is it? It is that despite staggering unemployment they are unwilling to hire adequate staff to answer the phones, since *your* time costs them nothing and is therefore valueless. Moreover, how can we hope to confirm that calls are answered in the order received, and why should that matter to us? Might this be one of those cases, like "I matter," where the felt need to say it is a probable sign that it is not true?

Comment: My question itself is, more simply, "should this message be rephrased, or is it sufficiently 'correct' or understandable?"  I don't care at all when my call gets answered; I accept my place as a worthless customer service caller.

Comment: I believe that the phrase is sufficiently correct due to the plurality of its usage.  Its the classic prescriptivism vs descriptivism debate: http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/10/prescriptivism-and-descriptivism/

Comment: I think the usage might be reconciled with prescriptivism by considering the greater context of the statement.  Yes, you are only a single caller, and you have placed a singular call, but the context of the statement is multiple calls.  Your call is one in an array of calls that need to be answered in a certain order.

Comment: While one thing cannot be placed "in order" by itself, it can be considered "in order" when compared to its peers.  Is this series in order? 1,2,3,4.  Is the bold numeral in order? 2,4,**6**,8.  A single item without any comparative context cannot be said to be in order, but I don't believe that is the case here.  Your call will be answered in the order it was received (in comparison to the other callers that are also on hold.)  Much like the 6 is in order when considered in the context of the series 2,4,6,8.

Comment: I've also heard *"Calls will be answered in the order in which they're received"* which makes more logical sense but who is really paying attention to the recorded message?  We're all pretty much saying to ourselves, **"Darn!  I'm on perma-hold!"** lol!

Comment: I find it mildly amusing that your question has been put 'on-hold' and the question still remains - will it be reviewed in the order it was received?

Comment: Ha! I did not notice this until now, somehow.  Yes; quite amusing.

Answer (score 3):

When you're wondering how natural a phrase is one thing to do is to consider how else it could be phrased. I'm having a really hard time thinking of anything that would be even approximately the same as the sentence in question. The closest I could come up with is:

> Your call will be answered according to the order it was received in.

Your suggested alternative ("Calls are answered in the order in which they were received.") is a very different sentence and pragmatically can't be considered to be a good alternative. This is because the original sentence focuses "your call", but this alternative does not. It is impersonal and the caller won't feel like they are being addressed properly.

This use of *order* is very common. Here are some more examples from the wild:

> [This ticket has been closed, and we’ll respond to your original request in the order it was received](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/21916)
>
> [They passed a microphone down the row, each calling a word in the order it was listed](http://dmhsrampage.com/4026/features/for-a-mental-athlete-memorizing-52-cards-in-the-right-order-is-a-slam-dunk/)
>
> [Each configured authentication method is examined in the order in which it is configured](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPREK_6.1.0/com.ibm.itame.doc_6.1/am61_webservers_admin77.htm%23wq135)
>
> [your ticket will come in to the cook in the order it was given](http://www.forbes.com/sites/larrymagid/2012/09/03/10-rules-for-restaurants/?commentId=comment_blogAndPostId/blog/comment/1886-1773-386)

It appears that this usage is more common with plural or mass nouns, but it's still fairly common with singular nouns.

So is it common and accepted? Definitely.

Answer (score 1):

It's an indication that your call is in a [First-In-First-Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO) queue.  From the Wikipedia,

> It is analogous to processing a queue with first-come, first-served (FCFS) behaviour: where the people leave the queue in the order in which they arrive.

It's an audible indication that they are processing the queue, since you cannot tell where you are in line. Further, that if you leave the queue and return you will start at the back of the line.

Comment: In your Wikipedia quote, the subject that is leaving the queue is plural.  This makes sense, but is it a requirement for that sentence?  Can you also say "each person will leave the queue in the order in which he or she arrives"?

Comment: @GeorgeCapote I can parse that question. What problem do you see with it?

Comment: A single person is singular.  Can a single person leave in a certain order?  Can a single call be answered in an order?  Don't you need multiple things for them to be in an order?

Comment: How many calls can you make on one phone? How many calls can you receive with one hundred phones and one hundred people? How many people are each of those people talking to? Hint: It's all of one (because a call is 1:1) and one hundred (because there are 100 conversations) or two hundred (because there are 200 people). English is ambiguous. You work it out with context. I guess the context is that a single person *is not* really a queue (outside of the mathematical sense).

Comment: You can make and receive as many calls as you'd like on any number of phones.  It remains, that each call you make is not *itself* done in an *order*.  The collective of all of the calls you make are made *in an order*.  A single call is just a single call, you cannot order it any differently.

Comment: But in this case, the speaker isn't making calls; the speaker is *receiving* calls. And clearly they receive calls in an order. If there was only one caller in the queue, either no one is working or the caller is *next*.

Comment: Exactly.  They receive calls (plural) in an order.  But when the message plays, it says that my call (singular) will be answered in an order.

Comment: Yes. Because your call is singular. Either you're wrong, or every bank I have ever had an account with (and various insurance companies) are *all* wrong. Which is possible, but I trust *them* with *my money*.

Comment: If my call is singular, how can it be answered in an order?  If I have a single piece of data, can I order it?  I can order several pieces of data in an array, but each single entity in the array will not be *in an order*.  The whole thing will be in an order.  Just like the whole pool of calls currently on hold are in an order, but each my particular call.

Comment: Your call isn't the only call. If it were you wouldn't be on hold. Please continue to hold. Your call is important to us. But not quite important enough to hire more staff and answer the phone.

Comment: I know that.  I'm not asking about how their answering system works, or how many people are calling.  I'm asking if they made an error in saying "Your call (singular, not orderable) will be answered in the *order* it was received."  As opposed to "Your calls (plural, which can be ordered) will be answered in the *order* in which *they* were received"

Comment: @GeorgeCapote You may feel it is awkward, you may hate it. But, it is perfectly clear English in context. And it is a very popular phrasing in my experience.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.  Is it correct, though, that the sentence in a strictly logical sense does not work?  In programming, for example, I think it'd be like calling an order numerically function on a single integer.

Comment: @GeorgeCapote it works for me. In programming, for example, the merge sort. A list of one element is sorted.

Answer (score -1):

I agree, there cannot be an order if there is only a single item.

It seems to be a paraphrase of the plural: "Your calls will be answered in the order in which they were received" (plural 'your'), which makes perfect sense.

Comment: Well sure it does, but is it also the case that their sentence makes no sense?  Or is it so understood and used by everyone that it's become a reasonable way to say what they mean?

Comment: Well, it's not correct, but it is understood. The problem is, I suppose, that there is no better way to convey what they mean. "Your call will be answered in due time"? "We'll answer your call when we get to it"? "There's a bloody queue young man"? How would you phrase it so it's both correct and polite?

Comment: The way you did, "Your," in this case, referring to all customers currently on hold.